# Angular: Http to HttpClient conversion issue

Tags: angular, typescript, http, service, observable

I'm working on the conversion from Http to HttpClient in my old Angular app. However, during work on the service.ts part, I can't resolve the following error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
> of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
> Arrays.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Rider } from "../interfaces/rider";
import { SpeedwayService } from "../../speedway.service";
import { OrderPipe } from "ngx-order-pipe";

@Component({
  selector: "gs-pgee2020",
  templateUrl: "./pgee2020.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./pgee2020.component.less"]
})
export class Pgee2020Component {
  pgee2020: Array<any>;
  order: string = "MSC";
  reverse: boolean = false;
  result: number[];
  constructor(
    private _speedwayService: SpeedwayService,
    private orderPipe: OrderPipe
  ) {
    this._speedwayService.getPgee2020().subscribe(response => {
      this.pgee2020 = orderPipe.transform(response, "MSC");
    });
  }

  setOrder(value: string) {
    if (this.order === value) {
      this.reverse = !this.reverse;
    }
    this.order = value;
  }
}
```

**service.ts (old, worked with Http)**

```
getPgee2020() {
    return this._http
      .get("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020")
      .map(result => (this.result = result.json().data));
  }
```

**service.ts (new, not working with HttpClient)**

```
getPgee2020() {
    return this._http
      .get("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020").pipe(map((result => (this.result = result))));
    }
```

**data structure**

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "604a882ed87fdb0482536fc9",
      "MSC": 3,
      "ZAWODNIK": "Bartosz Zmarzlik",
      "KLUB": "Gorzów",
      "SREDNIA": 2.43,
```

**component.html**

```
 <tr
            *ngFor="
              let rider of pgee2020 | orderBy: order:reverse;
              let i = index" class="row-zaw"
            [routerLink]="[rider.id]">
          
            <td>{{ rider.MSC }}</td>
            <td>{{ rider.ZAWODNIK }}</td>
            <td>{{ rider.KLUB }}</td>
...
```

Comment: I added the component.html to the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to iterate over the *data* property of `pgee2020` rather than the entire object itself, which is why your template breaks. The latter is an object and you can't iterate over it using the existing code.

Make the following change:

```
<tr *ngFor="let rider of pgee2020.data"> 
   .... 
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I'm still having the `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` in the console though. Any idea how to erase this?

Comment: You're welcome. Where are your writing this `console.log` statement?

Comment: Anywhere, this is not the console.log. I get two errors of this type with every load. However, the app seems to work properly and all data is displayed.

Comment: I'm sorry @Nicholas, but after upgrading my Angular to the newest version the problem returned. This time ` TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'any[]'`. I would appreciate any idea on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with the following change in the service.ts. Nicholas resolved the problem in Angular 5, my can help with Angular 11.

```
  getPgee2020() {
    return this._http
      .get("http://node.gurustats.usermd.net:60519/pgee2020").pipe(map(res => res ['data']))
```